# Disable scrolling when touch moving certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, touch

I have a page with a section to sketch a drawing in.  But the touchmove events, at least the vertical ones, are also scrolling the page (which degrades the sketching experience) when using it on a mobile browser.  Is there a way to either a) disable & re-enable the scrolling of the page (so I can turn it off when each line is started, but turn it back on after each is done), or b) disable the default handling of touchmove events (and presumably the scrolling) that go to the canvas the sketch is drawn in (I can't just disable them completely, as the sketching uses them)?

I've used jquery-mobile vmouse handlers for the sketch, if that makes a difference.

**Update**: On an iPhone, if I select the canvas to be sketched in, or just hold my finger for a bit before drawing, the page doesn't scroll, and not because of anything I coded in the page.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not gonna help you a lot in the form it is present there, but have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily). It deals with regular scrolling, but maybe you could use it.

Answer (score 234):

Set the [touch-action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) CSS property to `none`, which works even with [passive event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners):

```
touch-action: none;
```

Applying this property to an element will not trigger the default (scroll) behavior when the event is originating from *that* element.

Comment: That seems to also kill `touchstart` events so not useful if you want to recognize touch events but not allow scrolling.

Comment: @Badrush -- Are you sure? I'm using this on my own "draggable" components, and `touchstart` fires just fine.

Comment: Works great for a canvas element (just put style="touch-action: none" right in the html). What could be simpler! Other solutions from this page failed for me. Thanks!

Comment: This won't prevent it from moving if the visitor doesn't do a mouse up. So basically, it can't be applied dynamically while dragging.

Comment: @Alvaro, in what situation would you need to dynamically apply it? [Here's how it appear to be expected to be used](https://jsgist.org/?src=96f9293f224c6354f62a658dac99db05) You already know the element you don't want to scroll so just mark that element as `touch-action: none`?

Answer (score 51):

> **Note:** As pointed out in the comments by @nevf, this solution may no longer work (at least in Chrome) [due to performance changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/01/scrolling-intervention). The recommendation is to use [`touch-action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) which is also suggested by @JohnWeisz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43275544/1676444).

Similar to the answer given by @Llepwryd, I used a combination of `ontouchstart` and `ontouchmove` to prevent scrolling when it is on a certain element.

Taken as-is from a project of mine:

```
window.blockMenuHeaderScroll = false;
$(window).on('touchstart', function(e)
{
    if ($(e.target).closest('#mobileMenuHeader').length == 1)
    {
        blockMenuHeaderScroll = true;
    }
});
$(window).on('touchend', function()
{
    blockMenuHeaderScroll = false;
});
$(window).on('touchmove', function(e)
{
    if (blockMenuHeaderScroll)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Essentially, what I am doing is listening on the touch start to see whether it begins on an element that is a child of another using jQuery `.closest` and allowing that to turn on/off the touch movement doing scrolling. The `e.target` refers to the element that the touch start begins with.

You want to prevent the default on the touch move event however you also need to clear your flag for this at the end of the touch event otherwise no touch scroll events will work.

This can be accomplished without jQuery however for my usage, I already had jQuery and didn't need to code something up to find whether the element has a particular parent.

Tested in Chrome on Android and an iPod Touch as of 2013-06-18

Comment: I found this worked for my needs `$(".carousel").on('touchstart', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });` which prevents up and down scroll on my carousel :)

Comment: Chrome now ignore event.preventDefault() for touch events, so this won't work. See: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/01/scrolling-intervention

Comment: Thank @nevf, I've added a note to my answer pointing that out and referring to JohnWeisz's answer for what seems to be the recommended approach. Glad to know my approach at least lasted a few years. 

Answer (score 31):

There is a little "hack" on CSS that also allows you to disable scrolling:

```
.lock-screen {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Adding that class to the body will prevent scrolling.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly on iphone / ipad. Thanks!

Comment: This solution is the best. I tried both the accepted one and the most voted one. Both didn't worked. This one is clean and lightweight.

Comment: that works when we do not need scroll but `touch-action: none;` allows having a scroll that cannot be scrolled in touch devices; it is practical when `scrollbar-width` is none.

Answer (score 19):

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {e.preventDefault()}, false);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {e.preventDefault()}, false);
```

This should prevent scrolling, but it will also break other touch events unless you define a custom way to handle them.

Comment: I had tried this with ontouchmove, which did disable scrolling, but I wasn't able to get it back.

Comment: There is one important thing missing: you need to set `{passive: false}`

`document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleEndEventFn, { passive: false });`

Comment: I found that just disabling `touchmove` but instead of binding the eventlistener to the document I binded it directly to the canvas element helped prevent scrolling when using the canvas but allowed `touchstart` to work since I didn't prevent it.

Comment: How do I get the touchmove back? I tried to call `document.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleFn)`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @newman To successfully remove it you have to have all parameters exactly as when you added it including the { passive: false }

Comment: @johncl according to MDN, [you do not have to have all the parameters exactly as when you added it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). You have to have the same function object and the same 'capture'/'useCapture' setting

Answer (score 6):

The ultimate solution would be setting `overflow: hidden;` on `document.documentElement` like so:

```js
/* element is an HTML element You want catch the touch */
element.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
});

document.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'auto';
});
```

By setting `overflow: hidden` on start of touch it makes everything exceeding window hidden thus removing availability to scroll anything (no content to scroll).

After `touchend` the lock can be freed by setting `overflow` to `auto` (the default value).

It is better to append this to `<html>` because `<body>` may be used to do some styling, plus it can make children behave unexpectedly.

EDIT:
About `touch-action: none;` - Safari doesn't support it [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: This worked for me on iPad (iOS 13) where I only want one item at a time to be moveable. e.preventDefault(); doesn’t seem to prevent the srceen from moving.

Answer (score 2):

To my surprise, the "preventDefault()" method is working for me on latest Google Chrome (version 85) on iOS 13.7. It also works on Safari on the same device and also working on my Android 8.0 tablet.
I am currently implemented it for 2D view on my site here:
https://papercraft-maker.com

Answer (score 1):

try overflow hidden on the thing you don't want to scroll while touch event is happening.  e.g set overflow hidden on Start and set it back to auto on end.

Did you try it ?  I'd be interested to know if this would work.

```
document.addEventListener('ontouchstart', function(e) {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}, false);

document.addEventListener('ontouchmove', function(e) {
    document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
}, false);
```

Comment: I'm not clear on how to use this; where/when do these calls get made?  How does normal scrolling get restored once the "touch" is done (touchmove doesn't designate the END of the touch, just a movement WITHIN a touch, as I understand it).

Comment: normal scrolling would be restored by setting overflow back to auto. In effect you are removing the scrollbars and thus the scrollability of the body in this case.  So you would need to reenable it when you are done with the gesture that the unwanted scrolling is affecting. Would that be ontouchend ?

Comment: this was my initial thought but it is not working on mobile

Answer (score 1):

I found that `ev.stopPropagation();` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me on iphone

```
$(".owl-carousel").on('touchstart', function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault();      
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a button which, when clicked, opens a div scrollable on the y-axis. On mobile, scrolling the div scrolls the whole page, and the `touch-action` CSS property doesn't help.

What I did was "redirect" the document scrolling to the element when the start of the touch originates from the element.

```js
let touch_active = false;
let previous_y;
let element_to_scroll = document.querySelector('#your-element');

function is_element_to_scroll_open() {
    // Your logic goes here.
    return true;
}

document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    let open = is_element_to_scroll_open();
    let within_boundaries = e.composedPath().includes(element_to_scroll);

    if (open && within_boundaries) {
        touch_active = true;
        previous_y = e.touches[0].clientY;
    }
}, {passive: false});

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    if (touch_active) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let current_y = e.touches[0].clientY;
        let scroll_difference = current_y - previous_y;
        element_to_scroll.scrollTop = element_to_scroll.scrollTop - scroll_difference;
        previous_y = current_y;
    }
}, {passive: false});

document.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    if (touch_active) {
        touch_active = false;
        previous_y = null;
    }
}, {passive: false});
```

Answer (score -1):

the modern way (2022) of doing this is using pointer events as outlined here in the mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events

Pointer events build on touchstart and other touch events and actually stop scroll events by default along with other improvements.

Comment: AFAICT [pointerevents don't handle this case in Safari](https://greggman.github.io/doodles/test/prevent-scroll/touch%20events%20vs%20pointer%20events.html)