# Is there any way to make mobile screen scrollable?

Tags: css, webkit

I need to make my mobile screen scrollable. For that i am using css property named - webkit-overflow-scroll: touch . but the browser says it is "Unknown Property name". Can any body tell me what is it means ?? . if anybody knows the alternative to this Please tell me ?

Comment: Aren't all mobile screens scrollable?

Comment: actually i am using hamburger menu. I that menu when the options are more than 10 it should give scrollable functionality. it is not supporting using touch but it is supporting using mouse scroll. i checked that one using remote debugging. is there any solution?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

All touchscreens are scrollable by nature.

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Notice is different to yours (**scrolling** not scroll) is for 'lazy scrolling' which means rather than the default of stopping immediately when you stop the action with your finger it uses momentum so the content continues to scroll for a while after finishing the scroll gesture and removing your finger from the touchscreen. It also uses speed to determine the momentum and time it takes to stop scrolling, kind of like in real life.

I am fairly sure you cant stop scrolling in css but think there are some techniques available using javascript. Here is a question on SO talking about disabling touch scroll but I presume thats not what you want? [Disable scrolling when touch moving certain element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348031/disable-scrolling-when-touch-moving-certain-element)