# disable vertical scrolling on touch device while using owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when dragging horizontal carousel left to right on touch device it also allows it to be dragged up and down which jiggles the whole page around. How can I disable vertical scrolling on owl carousel. 
I can post the js file if anyone can help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please detail more your question, as written is too broad, primarly opinion based and subject to be closed soon. See here on how to ask question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Basically all I ask is how to disable vertical scrolling on owl carousel on touch device/mobile devices

Comment: Hi, @in00b. Have you found an answer to your question?

Answer (score 7):

Awesome css3 :)

```
.owl-carousel
{
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I needed!

Comment: This does not work for me. Using owl carousel 2.3., and the code above does nothing for me at all. Same for the other solution posted. I added the CSS directly to the source code. No effect (actually, pan-y is already used in the owl)

Comment: @Pointi Nice :)

Comment: This title is related to vertical @ArminHierstetter

Comment: This applies also to <v-tabs> element of Vuetify

Comment: Genius! Still a valid answer after almost 6 years man.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work for me, at least on iOS, haven't tested on Android.

When you start sliding with mouse or touch I saw that Owl Carousel adds the class .owl-grab to the slider. I then found this code from @Turnerj and just put .owl-grab in the code.

[Disable scrolling when touch moving certain element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348031/disable-scrolling-when-touch-moving-certain-element)

It also works with multiple sliders on same page. Hope this helps! (I'm new to jQuery so there could probably be flaws to this solution)

```
window.blockMenuHeaderScroll = false;
$(window).on('touchstart', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('.owl-grab').length == 1) {
        blockMenuHeaderScroll = true;
    }
});
$(window).on('touchend', function() {
    blockMenuHeaderScroll = false;
});
$(window).on('touchmove', function(e) {
     if (blockMenuHeaderScroll) {
        e.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

Comment: Does not work for me. The events do not even fire. When I add a console.log to either handler, they never fire. Not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Use hammer.js with addEventListner for Classes.
I have tested with iOS (iphoneX) and Android (Nexus 5X) and work like a charme.
I hope can help!

```
window.blockMenuHeaderScroll = true;
        var mc = new Hammer(document);
        var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("elenco_image");

        mc.on("swipeleft swiperight panleft panright", function(ev) {
            console.log(ev.type + " gesture detected.");
            window.blockMenuHeaderScroll = true;
        });

        mc.on("swipeup swipedown panup pandown", function(ev) {
            console.log(ev.type + " gesture detected.");
            window.blockMenuHeaderScroll = false;
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
            classname[i].addEventListener('touchmove', function(evt) {
                if (blockMenuHeaderScroll) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                }

            }, {
                passive: false
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.owl-carousel 
{
-ms-touch-action: pan-x;
touch-action: pan-x; 
}
```

This worked for me as I need only horizontal scroll. Above code restricts the vertical scroll.

Comment: Perfect, I can confirm this works :)

Answer (score 1):

This will block vertical scrolling while dragging the image horizontally,
or prevent the horizontal pan while trying to v-scroll the page itself.

Important: Attach the event **directly** to the IMG element.

```
let blockScroll = false;
let blockPan = false;

$('.owl-carousel img').on('touchstart', '', ots);
$('.owl-carousel img').on('touchmove', '', otm);

let p0 = [0,0];

function ots(ev) { //save the first touch point
  p0 = [ev.touches[0].screenX, ev.touches[0].screenY];
  blockScroll = false;
  blockPan = false;
}

function otm(event){
    if(blockScroll)
      event.preventDefault(); //don't let the window v-scroll
    else if(blockPan)
    { //don't let OWL get the event and pan-x.
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
    else
    { //calculate distance from the first touch point on every move
      let t = event.touches[0];
      let dx = t.screenX - p0[0];
      let dy = t.screenY - p0[1];

      if( Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy) )
      {
        blockScroll = true;
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      else
      {
        blockPan = true;
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }
    }
}
```

Tested on android (Chrome) and ios(Safari).

Answer (score 1):

Some improvements on @Giovanni Locombi's answer to make the touch actions smoother. Works on iOS

Using Hammer.js from https://hammerjs.github.io/

```
    window.blockMenuHeaderScroll = false;
    var mc = new Hammer(document);
    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("owl-carousel");

    mc.on("swipeleft swiperight panleft panright", function(ev) {
        window.blockMenuHeaderScroll = true;
    });

    mc.on("panend swipeend", function (ev){
        window.blockMenuHeaderScroll = false;
    });

    mc.on("swipeup swipedown panup pandown", function(ev) {
        window.blockMenuHeaderScroll = false;
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
        classname[i].addEventListener('touchmove', function(evt) {
            if (blockMenuHeaderScroll) {
                evt.preventDefault();
            }

        }, {
            passive: false
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have tried so many solutions , but above works well for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me.
but this worked.

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage, .owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item{
    -ms-touch-action: auto;
        touch-action: auto;
}
```