# Disable page scrolling on mobile device on move touch on graph(stock chart) of highcharts in Ionic 2 and angular 2

Tags: angular, highcharts, ionic2

I have used stock chart of Highcharts with Ionic 2 and Angular 2. I want to stop/disable page scrolling when I movetouch on graph on mobile device. I enabled **followTouchMove** of tooltip to get graph data.
I really appreciate if someone help me.

Comment: There are multiple answers for that if you search that question in google - e.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348031/disable-scrolling-when-touch-moving-certain-element