# How to stop scrolling the previous page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing a website and want to stop users go to the previous page when they scroll with two fingers on their touchpad. I tried to add scroll event and stop propagation but it doesn't work.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {e.stopPropagation()});
document.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {e.stopPropagation()});
document.addEventListener('touchend', (e) => {e.stopPropagation()});
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

I have tried to disable touch-action in css but it still doesn't work:

```
touch-action: none;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable scrolling when touch moving certain element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348031/disable-scrolling-when-touch-moving-certain-element)

Comment: In short, touch scrolling does not trigger the `scroll` event. It triggers `touchstart` and `thouchend` events. The browser detects events from both fingers, compiles them together and determines behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I use below code to solve the issue:

```
export const disableScroll = () => {
    windowOnweel = window.onwheel;
    window.onwheel = e => {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = false;
    }; 
};
```

but you need to remember to restore the onwheel method when you don't need that.