# Prevent children from grabbing all touch events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to prevent from a component (such as a slider or a chart) from grabbing touch move and similar events?
The problem occurs when trying to slide up or down a page with such a component from an external library on a touch-screen device.

I tried the Capture synthetic events which didn't help:

```
  <div className='wrapper'
    onTouchMoveCapture={(e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }}
   ...
```

Comment: Completely unrelated but that title is rather interesting XD

Comment: css pointer-evnets: none [MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) but this can break other features.

Comment: This is one of those things that is a cross-browser nightmare. Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348031/disable-scrolling-when-touch-moving-certain-element

Comment: I clicked here expecting to read some parenting tips